# How to get the 'characters moved distance" for a HTML5 input field

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get how far the first character is moved from its original place in an input field.

Background: I'm trying to give syntax highlighting feature to an input field. I'm currently thinking of using multi-color rectangles placed below text to do this, so I have to consider how to place these rectangles at the exact same location with the text.

For example I have an input field like this, and the user inputs text. When the text length is greater than the width, the text gets moved to the left.

An example of this.

```html
<input type="text" id="listItemEditorInputDemo">
```

```css
#listItemEditorInputDemo {
    width: 100;
}
```

When the text length is not greater than the input field width

not greater:

[image]

When the text length is greater than the input field width. Note that the first character is pushed backwards.

greater

[image]

So how do I get how much the sentence is pushed backwards? I want a pure Javascript solution. Thank you.

Comment: Note that the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything "pushed backwards", but if you're trying to compare the width of the input to the width of the actual text, you might either copy the text into a hidden span (and use the span's width as a proxy for the text's width) -- or, if you can tolerate supporting only a fixed-width font, set the width of the input in `ch` units and simply count the characters.

Comment: @Rob Thanks. I'll fix it.

Comment: @Cat Thanks. I'll use this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let listItemEditorInputDemoScrollLeft = document.getElementById(`listItemEditorInputDemo`).scrollLeft;
```

worked best for me.
See [Element.scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft).